# fopen for writing but not exclusive

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I want to use `fopen("file", "w")` to open a file for writing but not exclusive. I.e. I want to have another process read the file while it is still open.

Note that I have a flush after every line so I won't miss anything. Writing will be idle at the time the other process reads from the file.

The documentation does not mention exclusive but experimenting shows that it is exclusive.

Is there a way?

Comment: Is this a C or C++ application? Is your target application environment Windows or Win/RT or something else? What standard are you targeting (C99, C++11, etc.)?

Comment: Which programming language does this target?

Comment: I'm using an old version of Borland C in Windows XP DOS command.com. So I doubt if any modern form of fopen will work. (Sorry I didn't mention that up front ... I just didn't think of it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shared access on files is an OS-specific feature. fopen is too generic and does not provide that kind of control. You would need to use something more specific. If you are using a microsoft platform (assuming since you tagged for VS 2015) you can use [_fsopen or _wfsopen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fsopen-wfsopen?view=vs-2015) - they have a third parameter to specify the shared access.

```
_fsopen("file", "w", _SH_DENYWR);
```

this will open the file for writing and allow others to read from it (but not write to it).

> The argument `shflag` is a constant expression consisting of one of
>   the following manifest constants, defined in `Share.h`.
>
> - Term         Definition
> - _SH_COMPAT Sets Compatibility mode for 16-bit applications.
> - _SH_DENYNO Permits read and write access.
> - _SH_DENYRD Denies read access to the file.
> - _SH_DENYRW Denies read and write access to the file.
> - _SH_DENYWR Denies write access to the file.

Other OS/platforms may support some variation of fsopen too.