# electron: ui and backend processes accessing the same log file on Windows

Tags: c++, node.js, logging, io, electron

### Goal

My electron-based app uses a C++ backend, which keeps a log file. I'd love to show the file content on a page of my Electron frontend.

The macOS version works as expected. I simply use node.js `fs` and `readline` libraries and to read the file on the fly, and then insert the parsed text into innerHTML.

### Problem

However, on Windows, the log file seems to be locked by the backend while the CRT `fopen` calls use appending mode "a". So node.js keeps getting exception

```
EBUSY: resource busy or locked open '/path/to/my.log'
```

To make it worse, I use a thirdparty lib for logging and it's internal is not that easy to hack.

### Code

Here is the Electron-side of code

```js
function OnLoad() {
    let logFile = Path.join(__dirname, 'logs', platformDirs[process.platform], 'my.log');

    let logElem = document.querySelector('.log');
    processLineByLine(logFile, logElem);
}
//
// helpers
//
async function processLineByLine(txtFile, outElement) {
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(txtFile);
  
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: fileStream,
      crlfDelay: Infinity
    });
    // Note: we use the crlfDelay option to recognize all instances of CR LF
    // ('\r\n') in input.txt as a single line break.
  
    for await (const line of rl) {
      // Each line in input.txt will be successively available here as `line`.
      console.log(`Line from file: ${line}`);
      outElement.innerHTML += line + '<br>';
    }
}
```

Here is the backend side of code

```cpp
inline bool OpenLogFile(FILE** ppLogFile) {
    TCHAR logPath[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD length = GetModuleFileName(NULL, logPath, MAX_PATH);
    bool isPathValid = false;
#if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_WIN8)
    PathCchRemoveFileSpec(logPath, MAX_PATH);
    HRESULT resPath = PathCchCombine(logPath, MAX_PATH, logPath, TEXT("my.log"));
    isPathValid = (resPath == S_OK);
#else
    PathRemoveFileSpec(logPath);
    LPWSTR resPath = PathCombine(logPath, logPath, TEXT("my.log"));
    isPathValid = (resPath != NULL)
#endif
    if (!isPathValid)
        return false;
    errno_t res = _wfopen_s(ppLogFile, logPath, L"a");
    if (res != 0) {
        wprintf(TEXT("Error: Failed to open log file: %s"), GetOSErrStr().c_str());
    }
    return res == 0;
}
```

### Question

Is this an inherent problem with my architecture?
Should I forget about accessing the log file from frontend/backend processes at the same time?
I thought about using a message queue for sharing logs between the frontend and backend processes, but that'd make logging more complex and bug prone.

Is there an easy way to have the same logging experience as with macOS?

Comment: What is the path of this log file?

Comment: It looks like you are attempting to write log inside the application directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself.

I must use [another Win32 API `_wfsopen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fsopen-wfsopen?view=vs-2019) that provides more sharing options.

In my case, the following change is sufficient

```cpp
*ppLogFile = _wfsopen(logPath, L"a+", _SH_DENYWR);
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54634637/987846) helped.