# Can't open file while program is running

Tags: c, windows, file, fopen

I made a simple program that takes input of the user and then prints it into a file. I made it inside a `while()` loop. It's just a text file. I was wondering: **I can't open my file by double clicking it while my program (that created the file) is running. After I close my program I can open the file by double clicking with my mouse on the file. Why? How can I work around it?**

```
        FILE* file;
        fopen_s(&f, "***", "w+");
```

Comment: Because that's how your OS was designed. It has nothing to do with the C program as such.

Comment: @Lundin Thank you for your answer. How can I work around it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54631617/fopen-for-writing-but-not-exclusive

Comment: With "w+" (open for reading and writing) there is no way that another process can safely access the file.  So no sharing is allowed.  You'll have more control over the sharing mode with _fsopen().

Comment: Use some OS-specific API. In Windows `CreateFile` and `ReadFile` etc come with lots of options.